# How to make the bot ignore its own name

Tags: nlp, dialogflow-es, chatbot, actions-on-google, jovo-framework

I'm working on a bot using Jovo4 and Google Actions (not Dialogflow) as NLP provider.

I've created an entity called ***contactName*** which has dozens of names and, as you may guess, it's used to identify names out of intents.

The problem is, the Bot has its onw name and it keeps identifying it as a ***contactName*** everytime the user mention it casually during the conversation.

How do I prevent the bot from identifying a specific value on an entity?

Is it possible to insert/classify "undesired" values?

Obs1: I didn't add the bot name as a trainning value

Obs2: Fuzzy Matching and the ability to "accept unknown values" is on because I need it.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to handle this is to create an intent intentionally to match these queries and redirect them appropriately, which may include responding to the user and stating what kinds of user queries are valid.